# Marshalling C++ struct with a int* member to C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a C++ structure below:

```
struct CTMDeviceError {
    struct CTMDeviceInfo sDeviceInfo;
    int32_t              iResultCode;
    int32_t              iExtendedResultCode;
    int32_t *            piDenomination;
    int32_t *            piChangeDue;
};
```

I have created an equivalent c# structure but I'm having trouble marshalling the int32 * type.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CTMDeviceError
{
    public CTMDeviceInfo deviceInfo;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 resultCode;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 extendedResultCode;

    public ??? denomination;

    public ??? changeDue;
};
```

I have tried using IntPtr or Int32[] but it Visual Studio shows mismatch errors.
Can I please get some advise?
Thanks!

This is the rest of the struct details:

**c++**

```
struct CTMDeviceInfo {
    enum CTMDeviceType eDeviceType;
    char *             szDeviceModel;
    char *             szDeviceSubModel;
    int32_t *          piDeviceID;
};

enum CTMDeviceType {
    CTM_DEVICETYPE_CASHCHANGER  = 5,
    CTM_DEVICETYPE_CASHACCEPTOR = 15,
    CTM_DEVICETYPE_COINACCEPTOR = 16,
    CTM_DEVICETYPE_OTHER        = 17
};
```

**c#**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CTMDeviceInfo
{
    public CTMDeviceType deviceType;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string deviceModel;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string deviceSubModel;

    public ??? deviceId;
};

public enum CTMDeviceType
    {
        CTM_DEVICETYPE_CASHCHANGER = 5,
        CTM_DEVICETYPE_CASHACCEPTOR = 15,
        CTM_DEVICETYPE_COINACCEPTOR = 16,
        CTM_DEVICETYPE_OTHER = 17
    };
```

Comment: If I use Intptr, the exe would just crash and send me a long error report which I didn't understand. If I use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] public Int32[] denomination, it gives me this => An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Additional information: Cannot marshal field 'deviceInfo' of type 'CTMOnCSharp.CTMDeviceError': The type definition of this field has layout information but has an invalid managed/unmanaged type combination or is unmarshalable.

Comment: I tried using [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] public System.IntPtr changeDue but I still got the mismatch error. Maybe my format is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type for pointers should be [`System.IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. The application crashed. VS gave me a long error report which I didn't understand. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the errors are due to the IntPtr? The deviceInfo looks more like it could be the culprit.

Comment: i have updated the description with added details to the struct.